# Qt5 http post to Facebook failed

Tags: facebook, qt, facebook-graph-api

I am a newbie in QT5.

I tried to write a program which can like a post on facebook using my access_token in QT5.

Here are my code snippet

Function use to do http post:

```
bool MainWindow::postRequest(QString link, QMap<QString, QString> data)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QUrl url(link);
    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "multipart/form-data");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36");
    QUrlQuery params;
    QByteArray postData;
    QStringList keys = data.keys();
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
    {
        params.addQueryItem(keys[i],data[keys[i]]);
    }
    postData.append(params.toString());
    qDebug() << QString(postData);
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, postData);
    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And when a button clicked, I call the function below:

```
void MainWindow::likeAct()
{
    QString postid = ui->postid->text(); //The id of my post
    QString token = ui->token->text(); //My access_token which had full permission
    QMap<QString,QString> data;
    data.insert("access_token",token);
        postRequest(QString("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/%1/likes").arg(postid),data);
}
```

The replyFinished function as following:

```
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR: " << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        QByteArray responseData = reply->readAll();
        QString qstr(responseData);
        qDebug() << "SUCCESS: " << qstr;
    }
}
```

The qDebug() in replyFinished printed:

```
ERROR:  "Error downloading https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/1041840172497418/likes - server replied: Forbidden"
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your account don't have enough permissions for uploading. Please check the 'scope' parameter when authorization to Facebook in progress (for API > 2.0 also 'publish_actions' permission are required):

```
QUrl CFacebookUrl::facebookLoginUrl() const
{
  QUrl url( baseUrl( buAuthorization ) );//https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
  {
    QUrlQuery query;
    query.addQueryItem( "client_id", "your_client_id" );
    query.addQueryItem( "redirect_uri", "your_redirect" );
    query.addQueryItem( "response_type", "code" );
    query.addQueryItem( "display", "page" );
    query.addQueryItem( "scope", "read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,user_photos" );
    url.setQuery( query );
  }
  return url;
}
```

Comment: I am sure that my token has full-permission because I already debug it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/